# DWA 171 not working

Tags: networking, drivers

I have been using a DWA 171 dongle for quite some time and didn't have any issues with it.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) to 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) today. Before I updated it, the dongle worked perfectly fine. But after the update was finished and restarted, it took some time to implement some stuff like dock appearance change, colour theme shift, etc, and after that, it restarted again automatically. This time, my DWA dongle was not working, the green light didn't glow.

I tested it on Windows, Mac and Kali, but it still didn't work. I tried using the `df` command to check the disks available, but the DWA dongle wasn't specified there. I surfed through a bunch of websites and tried using the `lsusb` command to see if it is being detected by the OS, and yes it did. Here is the output of `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0223 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Webcam-50
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:2000 Ralink Technology, Corp. CSR BS8510
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 2001:331d D-Link Corp. DWA-171
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here you can find the `D-Link Corp. DWA-171` device being shown. So please help me fix this issue.

Sorry for typing something this long, and thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Here's the output of `dkms status`:

```
$ dkms status
rtl8821CU/5.4.1, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Edit 2: I fixed the issue, all I did was update the drivers by following the instructions here: https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210118

Comment: (1) D-Link Corp. DWA-171 is a common WiFi USB dongle, not an "extender". (2) If the same symptom - not working - happens with other OSes then it has nothinbg to do with one OS in particular. It's either the device itself or the USB that's defective (assuming the other OSes you mention run in the same computer; if another then definitely it's the dongle). Either way, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Does the device work in a live session?

Comment: "I tested it on Windows, Mac and Kali, but it still didn't work." It's no longer functional. I suggest that you check here for many working out of the box USB wireless devices: https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status`. You need a dkms driver to run the DWA.

Comment: @heynnema Here is the output of `dkms status`:                                                `rtl8821CU/5.4.1, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks, I updated the question, I specified it as "dongle" at first but then I just thought that was akward.

Comment: @chili555 thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone, I fixed the issue!

Comment: @anonymous: you can put an answer by yourself, explaining the steps you performed

Comment: @LorenzKeel Thanks but I already know, I had NoScript turned on so I couldn't add an answer lol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, all I did was update the drivers by following the instructions here: https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210118

Comment: The link is dead